# Подключить OS X Extended на Windows 7

Tags: windows, macos, hdd, fat32

Всем привет! Подскажите, если кто знает или сталкивался, как подключить хард с OS X Extended на Windows 7, чтобы вытащить файлы.
Под рукой второго Мак-а нету, поэтому такой вопрос.

Comment: А какая там ФС?

Comment: Рассматривали вариант программы MacDrive?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов вроде как HFS+

Comment: @1d0 IMHO венда не умеет такую ФС, проще LiveCD с линухом и на флешку.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Рассматривал вариант с LiveCD, просто думал мб есть более быстрый вариант.
Насчет ФС, вроде NTFS.

Comment: @Goldy загрузиться с LiveCD - быстро.